# How to open an activity twice but with different content?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent

I'm developing a chat app, but I have a problem.
I've a list with the contacts and when I select one contact I'm starting a new activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MessageScreen.class);
startActivity(i);
```

but, when I choose another contact to talk I will use the same activity.
but it always open with the last contact screen and the variables still with the old values.

I would like to make something similar to google talk, where you can start to talk with another contact, and all the messages use the same screen, and you can change between the chats fast with no need to reconstruct the screen, reload the messages, etc..
Anyone have any idea of how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sliding between activities isn't a common feature, it sounds like there is one second activity that has a ViewPager that is populated with multiple chats. When starting this activity, they're probably adding the [Reorder to front flag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) to the intent and have overridden onNewIntent to add a new view to the pager.

Comment: That's right, it make much more sense, and also not so difficult to implement. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like*:

```
i.PutExtra ("key", value);
```

before starting the activity (e.g. store the user name) and then read your *value* from the activity and adjust (e.g. UI) it based on the value

*note*: syntax could differ a bit since I do my Android stuff from C#

Comment: I'm using extras to pass the contact id to load the messages.
I'm wondering if there are some way that I don't need to reload the messages each time. On google talk you can slide the chat windows from one to another, without see any loading, you can see both chat screens when you slide to next chat window.